# Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException. how can I display image on Imageview?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to parse the JSON file and trying to display JSON content on the list view. Here is my API content.

```
[
  {
    "photo": "https://c1.staticflickr.com/1/169/396525383_9140cca7c0.jpg",
    "author": "Toby Keller"
  },
  {
    "photo": "https://c1.staticflickr.com/1/62/205125225_65381511a5.jpg",
    "author": "Louis Vest"
  },
  {
    "photo": "https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4090/5171453436_92d3b3f287.jpg",
    "author": "Mike Behnken"
  },
  {
    "photo": "https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2557/3943872114_5bab1ed4ae.jpg",
    "author": "Luigi Alesi"
  },
  {
    "photo": "https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4088/4952370052_62daf4e03e.jpg",
    "author": "Eleder Jimenez Hermoso"
  }
]
```

I am able to get data from API but image format is not supported. How can I display the image on the image view?

This is what I tried:

```
Main Activity:

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val url = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText).text


        var load = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)

        load.setOnClickListener {
            AsyncTaskHandler().execute(url.toString())
        }

    }

    inner class AsyncTaskHandler:AsyncTask<String,String,String>() {

        override fun onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute()
            findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.loader).visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }

        override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: String?): String {

            return try {
                p0.first().let {
                    val url = URL(it)
                    val urlConnect = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
                    urlConnect.connectTimeout = 700
                    publishProgress(100.toString())
                    urlConnect.inputStream.bufferedReader().readText()

                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                p0.first().let {
                    val url = URL(it)
                    val urlConnect = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
                    urlConnect.disconnect().toString()
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
            super.onPostExecute(result)
            findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.loader).visibility = View.GONE

           jsonResult(result)
            Log.d("Fetched Data", result)

        }

       private fun jsonResult(jsonString: String?){
            val jsonArray = JSONArray(jsonString)
            val list=ArrayList<MyData>()
            var i = 0

            while(i<jsonArray.length()){
                val jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                list.add(
                    MyData(
                    jsonObject.getString("author"),
                    jsonObject.getString("photo")
                )
                )
                i++
            }

            val adapter = ListAdapter(this@MainActivity,list)
            val listView = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listView)
            listView.adapter = adapter

        }



    }


}
```

List_adapter:

```
    class ListAdapter(val context: Context, val list: ArrayList<MyData>):BaseAdapter() {
    override fun getView(p0: Int, p1: View?, p2: ViewGroup?): View {
        val view:View = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_row,p2,false)
        val photo = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.authImage)
        val author = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.authName)
        author.text=list[p0].author
        photo.setImageURI(Uri.parse(list[p0].photo))
        return view
    }

    override fun getItem(p0: Int): Any {
        return p0
    }

    override fun getItemId(p0: Int): Long {
        return p0.toLong()
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use third part library like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

Comment: Check your image URI. Is the link working or  corrupt

Comment: it's working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) Library to load image into an `ImageView`.

Using Glide is very simple.

`Glide.with(this).load("image url here").into(imageView)`

I hope it helps.